# Is the title of the site too confusing?

Tags: discussion

I don't know how close we are to go-live, or if this suggestion has any chance of being incorporated, but I wonder if a change to the site title might alleviate some confusion.

The #1 misconception that very single newcomer makes about the site is the idea that the site is a "Christian site".  It's not, of course, as discussed in [more posts than I care to link to](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), but everyone thinks it is at first.

Every so often an answer comes along that's beautiful (in my opinion) but really has no business on this site.  Example: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15137/i-want-to-become-a-christian-but-am-currently-an-atheist/15138#15138

I'm wondering if it's feasible to consider renaming the site to "Comparative Christianity" ***or some other title that better communicates the scope of the site*** rather than "Christianity" when we go live.

*Note, I'm not married to the idea of "Comparative Christianity".  It's just something I threw out there.  I am bringing up the question mainly (as it's tagged) as a discussion point in the hopes that a better title will be suggested.*

It fits the actual purpose of the site much more clearly.  While it might not prevent people from asking Truth questions and posting Truth answers, it might make it easier to explain to newcomers why such questions and answers are off-topic.

Comment: Related: [Should we rename our site to Christian Doctrine?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/813/214)

Comment: Yes that's better but it's a mouthful.

Answer (score 3):

Well maybe, but I wouldn't change it!

It's a good hook and drives with questions to the site. The odds are better that they stay if they register and ask a question than if they never register and never ask any questions.

For that reason, I'm not sure why hermeneutics hasn't just been renamed "Bible". But, then again, I'm not an SEOtician.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the site should reflect the interests of our audience. Comparative Christianity appeals to a person who is interested in comparing denominations on particular issues. Very few (almost none?) of our questions suggest that the person asking has this sort of motivation. Usually it is very clear that a specific denomination is being asked a question.

It would be more annoying to see novices ask "**comparative questions**" than it is to see them ask pastoral or Truth questions. We can shut those down easily. But if someone asks about "elaborate vestments in both the Catholic and Orthodox", then it is more difficult to give reasons for why the question should be shut down. The site is for people who *answer* questions, and, if I may, that is a terrible question. Among other issues, I can answer only half of it.

It would also be annoying to see "**comparative answers**". I would be fed up rather quickly if answers to questions directed towards a specific denomination took a "comparative" slant, and began to read "in contrast to Evangelicals, who think ..., Baptists think ...". When I *do* see someone clearly more familiar with another denomination answer questions on Catholicism, they very often get something important entirely wrong. I don't think we should encourage such answers.

"Comparative Christianity" doesn't seem to be a good replacement for "Christianity". It appeals to a different (and more-generic) subject, rather than simply a more-academic audience.